# C# cast options, is there any difference other than syntax?

Tags: c#, syntax

I just ran across another way to cast objects in C#.  I have always used `(CastType)variable`.  I just noticed some code using `variable as CastType`.  The latter reminds me of VB.

Is there a difference between the two methods of casting other than syntax?

Comment: This is a duplicate, thank you slavoo for finding that. I could not find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one will throw `InvalidCastException` if the types don't match (refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) - "Explicit conversions" section). The second one (the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) operator) will produce `null` value instead.